# Nodes aren't being saved to file in xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

I've been trying to save nodes into a java file "killsdeaths.xml" but after hours of debugging, it seems to be able to retrieve the values in the nodes correctly, but it doesn't save it. Can anybody help?

```
File f = new File("KillsDeaths.xml");
StatsRetrieve sr = new StatsRetrieve();
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public int[] giveKills(Player player, int kills) throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
    docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(f);
    OfflinePlayer offlineplayer = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(player.getName());
    offlineplayer.getUniqueId().toString();
    Node root = sr.getPlayerByUUID((Player)offlineplayer);
    Node killsnode = root.getFirstChild();
    int kills2 = Integer.parseInt(killsnode.getTextContent());
    int killsadded = kills2 + kills;
    String backtostring = Integer.toString(killsadded);
    killsnode.setTextContent(backtostring);
    killsnode.setNodeValue(backtostring);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(f);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Done.");
    int[] array = {kills2, killsadded};
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am blind, you forgot to attach your nodes to the document object.

Comment: Well that was the worst mistake I've ever done. Thanks a lot!